# Is GA-F2A68HM-S1 motherboard compatible with DDR3 ECC RDIMM?

Tags: compatibility, hardware-rec

I want to add memory to my computer. I would like to add `8GB (1 x 8GB) DDR3 1866 (PC3 14900) 1Rx4 240-Pin 1.5V ECC RDIMM Registered Memory by NEMIX RAM` to my  computer. Is  `GA-F2A68HM-S1` motherboard compatible with this memory sticks?

Comment: [Your motherboard does not support ECC memory.](http://download.gigabyte.us/FileList/Memory/mb_memory_ga-f2a68hm-s1.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I do not see ECC as an option for your motherboard.

Typically a motherboard that doesn't handle ECC will refuse to boot when presented with ECC RAM. ECC works different than normal memory as the CPU and motherboard must support ECC operations.

If you have it laying around you could try it. If you are buying it used or new then I would say no, you are wasting your time and funds.

Ross

Comment: ECC memory is not compatible with the author's motherboard

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want non ECC RAM. Your CPU and your motherboard need to support ECC. If this is a personal desktop, and not a server, there is no need to use ECC. Getting the same modules, in non-ECC, will also probably be half the price.

This page from [Mr Memory](https://www.mrmemory.co.uk/memory-ram-upgrades/gigabyte/motherboard/ga-f2a68hm-s1) shows that the data integrity is Non-ECC. I couldn't find that exact information in the Gigabyte documentation.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-F2A68HM-S1-rev-11#sp shows what memory works. ECC is not listed, therefore ECC won't work. DDR3 2400(OC)/2133/1866/1600/1333 MHz memory modules will work, and the 2400s provide maximum performance. You have a pair of memory module sockets, and a maximum of 64GB of RAM. AMD Memory Profile (AMP)/ Extreme Memory Profile (XMP) memory modules will also work, but will be spendier.